# How to implement Facebook Realtime Update Subscription with callback URL

Tags: java, facebook, web-services, restfb

How to implement [Facebook Realtime API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3)

Comment: Why are you answering your own question?

Comment: Contributing to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configure Facebook app and then install the app on Facebook pages/users that you want updates for.
2. We need to maintain a callback URL for Facebook to be able to post updates. Jersey based implementation as an example:

   ```
           @Path("/social/facebook/update")
           public class FacebookRealtimeAPIResource
           {
               private static final String HUB_MODE = "hub.mode";
               private static final String HUB_CHALLENGE = "hub.challenge";
               private static final String HUB_VERIFY_TOKEN = "hub.verify_token";

               public FacebookRealtimeAPIResource()
               {
                   // any desired implementation here
               }

               @GET
               @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
               public void validateFacebookRequest(
               @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam(HUB_MODE) String hubMode,
               @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam(HUB_CHALLENGE) String hubChallenge,
               @DefaultValue("") @QueryParam(HUB_VERIFY_TOKEN) String hubVerifyToken,
               @Context HttpServletRequest request,
               @Context HttpServletResponse response)
               {

                   try
                   {
                       // hubVerifyToken based validation if desired       
                       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                       response.getWriter().write(hubChallenge);
                       response.getWriter().flush();
                       response.getWriter().close();
                   }
                   catch (IOException exc)
                   {
                       throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
                   }
               }

               @POST
               @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
               public void processFacebookRealtimeUpdate(@Context HttpServletRequest request, InputStream inputStream)
               {
                   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                   String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                   String line;
                   String json = "";

                   try
                   {
                       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, request.getCharacterEncoding()));
                       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                       sb.append(line).append(newLine);
                   }
                   catch (Exception exc)
                   {
                       throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);
                   }
                   json = sb.toString(); // use this json string for desired purpose
               }
           }
   ```
3. Install app for page and then subscribe for page updates

   ```
           public class FacebookRealtimeSubscriber
           {
               private AccessToken appAccessToken = null;
               private String appSecret = // your app secret
               private String userAccessToken = // access token for user that owns the page, generated using your app
               private String applicationId = // your application id
               private String callbackURL = "<your context root>/social/facebook/update";
               private String pageName = // page name you want to install app for
               private FacebookClient client = null;
               private final String subscribedAppsEdge = "/subscribed_apps";
               private final String appSubscriptions = "/subscriptions";
               private final String verifyToken = "AnyRandomVerifyToken";
               // below are all the fields that can be subscribed for page object
               private final String pageFields = "feed,ratings,name,picture,category,description,founded,company_overview,conversations,mission,products,general_info,location,hours,parking,public_transit,phone,email,website,attire,payment_options,culinary_team,general_manager,price_range,restaurant_services,restaurant_specialties,videos,release_date,genre,starring,screenplay_by,directed_by,produced_by,studio,awards,plot_outline,network,season,schedule,written_by,band_members,hometown,current_location,record_label,booking_agent,press_contact,artists_we_like,influences,band_interests,bio,affiliation,birthday,personal_info,personal_interests,members,built,features,mpg,checkins,productlists";

               public static void main(String[] args)
               {
                   new FacebookRealtimeSubscriber().subscribe();
               }

               private void subscribe()
               {
                   String pageAccessToken = "";
                   String pageId = "";
                   client = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_3);
                   appAccessToken = client.obtainAppAccessToken(applicationId, appSecret);
                   client = new DefaultFacebookClient(userAccessToken, Version.VERSION_2_3);
                   Connection<Account> pages = client.fetchConnection("me/accounts", Account.class);
                   List<Account> accounts = pages.getData();
                   for (Account account : accounts)
                   {
                       if (pageName.equals(account.getName()))
                       {
                           pageAccessToken = account.getAccessToken();
                           pageId = account.getId();
                       }
                   }
                   client = new DefaultFacebookClient(pageAccessToken, appSecret, Version.VERSION_2_3);
                   // subscribe app for page
                   Object obj = client.publish(pageId + subscribedAppsEdge, JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("id", Long.valueOf(pageId)));
                   System.out.println(obj.toString());
                   // list subscriptions for app
                   obj = client.fetchObject(pageId + subscribedAppsEdge, JsonObject.class);
                   System.out.println(obj.toString());
                   // subscribe for page updates for app
                   client = new DefaultFacebookClient(appAccessToken.getAccessToken(), appSecret, Version.VERSION_2_3);
                   obj = client.publish(applicationId + appSubscriptions,
                   JsonObject.class,
                   Parameter.with("object", "page"),
                   Parameter.with("callback_url", callbackURL),
                   Parameter.with("fields", pageFields),
                   Parameter.with("verify_token", verifyToken));
                   System.out.println(obj);
                   // get subscriptions for app
                   obj = client.fetchObject(applicationId + appSubscriptions, JsonObject.class);
                   System.out.println(obj);
               }
           }
   ```